# Strange search criteria in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tags, search

I am daily follower of Stack Overflow and I have seen one weird tag. When I click on a particular tag then all the questions regarding that tag will be display, right? Check this image: [image]

Is this correct? Shouldn't it only display JavaScript questions here?

Comment: Caching. The question was [originally tagged \[javascript\]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20610663/revisions).

Comment: May be a cache issue? More often than not, it is that only. Some question was tagged with `javascript` before and was later re-tagged by removing it but the cache refused to update that and thus the confusion ;)

Comment: but this one is the issue right? @R.J

Comment: @Antony right but it should be refresh cache

Comment: Yeah it is. But nothing with SO as such, to call it a bug. It is a cache issue.

Comment: @dholakiyaankit That will take some time. That's why it's called caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a caching issue (stack exchange side), the [tag] pages are cached and only recreated periodically, as this question was previously tagged [javascript] in will remain on this page for a time until the cache is updated.

As you can see in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20610663/revisions) the javascript tag was removed 9 minutes ago.

[image]

This situation will resolve itself quickly and is the price we pay for the responsiveness of stack exchange sites.